# Creating a unique id by combining different types

Tags: c++, templates, generic-programming, entity-component-system

I want to create a unique id by "combining" types. The order of input types shouldn't matter and inputting the same combination of types should always return the same id (in the same runtime). I want to use this in an Entity Component System to identify combinations of components.

An idéa that almost does the job:

```cpp
    class Archetype
    {
    public:
        template <typename... Types>
        static uint32_t CreateArchetype()
        {
            return GetArchetypeIndex<Types...>();
        }
 
    private:
        template <typename... Types>
        static uint32_t GetArchetypeIndex()
        {
            static uint32_t index = GetNewArchetypeIndex();
            return index;
        }

        static uint32_t GetNewArchetypeIndex()
        {
            static uint32_t lastID = 0u;
            return ++lastID;
        }
    };
```

```cpp
int main()
{
    std::cout << Archetype::CreateArchetype<uint16_t, uint32_t, int, bool>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << Archetype::CreateArchetype<uint16_t, uint32_t, int, bool>() << std::endl;

    // Same Types but different order
    std::cout << Archetype::CreateArchetype<int, bool, uint16_t, uint32_t>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << Archetype::CreateArchetype<int, bool, uint16_t, uint32_t>() << std::endl;
}
```

`Output: 1, 1, 2, 2` `Goal: 1, 1, 1, 1`

This will return a unique id but it does care about order. Maybe this can be fixed by somehow ordering the types in `CreateArchetype()` function with some "variadic template sorting magic", but I haven't managed to do that, is it possible or is there some other options?

Answer (score 0):

Well there might be a way to do "variadic template sorting magic", but if you don't need the ID to be available at compile-time, nor to be sorted, you could just use [std::type_info::hash_code](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/hash_code) for each sub types do some non-fancy commutative operation (like a sum), and use this result as an id.

However, take into account that this result is not guaranteed to be unique, and you might want to use the names of these types, sort and concatenate the result, then hash it.

I edited your code to show an example of the naive approach using a sum.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <valarray>
#include <typeinfo>


    class Archetype
    {
    public:
        template <typename... Types>
        static uint32_t CreateArchetype()
        {
            return GetArchetypeIndex<Types...>();
        }

    private:
        template <typename... Types>
        static uint32_t GetArchetypeIndex()
        {
            std::valarray<size_t> a = { typeid(Types).hash_code()... };
            return a.sum();
            //static uint32_t index = GetNewArchetypeIndex();
            //return index;
        }

        static uint32_t GetNewArchetypeIndex()
        {
            static uint32_t lastID = 0u;
            return ++lastID;
        }
    };

int main()
{
    std::cout << Archetype::CreateArchetype<uint16_t, uint32_t, int, bool>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << Archetype::CreateArchetype<uint16_t, uint32_t, int, bool>() << std::endl;

    // Same Types but different order
    std::cout << Archetype::CreateArchetype<int, bool, uint16_t, uint32_t>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << Archetype::CreateArchetype<int, bool, uint16_t, uint32_t>() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I actually did something similar to this and had it as an example before I edited this question. But I think that hashing might not be the best solution because of the collisions risk. And i think the collision risk might be greater because of the type of data that is used where there might be alot combinations that uses almost the same types, But i might be wrong.

Comment: Well that's why I suggested to build a string using types names, then hashing it. String hashes are used in associative container of the stl, and I haven't seen collision, so I'd guess it should not happen in an ECS.

Comment: If you ever get collisions, or if you fear you could have some, you could also use cryptographic hash function, and avoid re-computing the "strong" hash by using an unsigned_map (which have ways to handle collisions).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution to me provided you have unique indices for each component type densely packed is to use a bitset for the unique ID. Ex:

```
// Order doesn't matter.
std::bitset<total_num_types> ent_id = (1ull << uint16_t_idx) |
                                      (1ull << uint32_t_idx) |
                                      (1ull << int_idx) |
                                      (1ull << bool_idx);
```

Can put that behind a nice variadic function template.